# Prove that characteristic polynomial = minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

Let $M \in M_{3}(K)$ whereby $K$ is a field, such that $\chi_{M}$ only has one root in $K$.

Show: $\chi_{M}=\mu_{M}$ whereby $\mu_{M}$ is the minimal polynomial.

Steps I thought about:

Let $\lambda \in K$ be this root. This means $\chi_{M}=(X-\lambda)^{3}= (X^{3}-3\lambda X^{2}+3\lambda^{2}X+\lambda^{3}Id)$.

By the Cayley-Hamilton we get:

$0=\chi_{M}(M)=M^{3}-3\lambda M^{2}+3\lambda^{2}M+\lambda^{3}Id$

What now?

Comment: By one root what do you mean about multiplicity ? For example with $M=\lambda Id$ you have $\chi_M=(X-\lambda)^3$ but $\mu_M=X-\lambda$ so your demonstration start the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Delta-u has noted, you are interpreting the statement wrongly. The problem states that if one of the roots of $\chi_{M}$ is in $K$, and the two other roots are not in $K$ (but of course in some extension field of $K$), then $\chi_{M} = \mu_{M}$.

The assumption implies that
$$
\chi_{M} = (x - \lambda) f,
$$
where $\lambda \in K$, and $f \in K[x]$ is a monic quadratic polynomial, which is irreducible over $K$.

Now you should know that $\mu_{M}$ divides $\chi_{M}$, and every root of $\chi_{M}$ is also a root of $\mu_{M}$.

Thus $\mu_{M}$ can be either $x - \lambda$ or $\chi_{M}$. But if $\mu_{M} = x - \lambda$, then $M$ is the scalar matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda\\\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
so that
$\chi_{M} = (x - \lambda)^{3}$, a contradiction.